# Plane Image not showing on the Shading & Camera view

Tags: rendering, camera, image

I have put one letter image on the object and I could see image in modeling view.
But when I check the Camera view to see what it will look like on render, It doesn't show up.

Does anyone knows what is happening here?
[image]
[image]

Thank you!
Best regards

Comment: it may be caused by your materials' opacity settings. May you share your blender file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hello, Here you are. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=v4g5xNm4" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/v4g5xNm4/) Thank you for the help!!

Comment: the image files are missing in your provided blender file so I can't really debug the problem. But I can see that all your materials have `Blend Mode` and `Shadow Mode` set to `Opaque`. Try to set it to `Alpha Blend` or `Alpha Hashed`

Comment: Under `Material (Properties)` -> `Settings`

Comment: It worked with the Alpha Hased mode. Thank you so much!! :)